# Режим разделëнного экрана

Tags: android, react-native

Возникла такая проблема...

При изменении размера приложения, в режиме разделëнного экрана(двойной экран), возникают вылеты приложения.

Изменения размера, а именно увеличение размера и выход из этого режима.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.mybday.birthdays/host.exp.exponent.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expo encountered a fatal error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'host.exp.exponent.j host.exp.exponent.j.c(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4279)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4311)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expo encountered a fatal error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'host.exp.exponent.j host.exp.exponent.j.c(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
    at host.exp.exponent.experience.q.F(BaseExperienceActivity.java:7)
    at host.exp.exponent.experience.a.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6970)
    at host.exp.exponent.experience.q.E(BaseExperienceActivity.java:2)
    at host.exp.exponent.experience.q.onResume(BaseExperienceActivity.java:5)
    at host.exp.exponent.experience.ExperienceActivity.onResume(ExperienceActivity.java:1)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1454)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8050)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4269)
    ... 11 more
```

**Если честно, я даже не знаю, что вам предоставить из кода, приложение и так мелкое. Используется библиотека react-native-router-flux**

P.S. у меня не хватает 2 балла, для комментариев, даже не знаю, как общаться, буду рад, если поможете с этой проблемой. :(

Comment: Добавил баллы - общайтесь

Comment: @Barmaley благодарю <3